# Can temporary NSManagedObjectID be archived?

Tags: cocoa, serialization, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

For permanent `NSManagedObjectID`, I know you can archive their `URIRepresentation` and get back the `NSManagedObjectID` later using the persistant store.

```
NSURL *uriRep = [objectId URIRepresentation];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = ...
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ...
NSManagedObjectID *myID = [psc managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:uriRep];
NSManagedObject *myObj = [context objectWithID:myID];
```

However, what if the ID is temporary? Is there a way to still turn it into NSString or NSData and get it back later, bypassing the persistent store, and use it directly with the context? This could be useful for some temporary objects.